# Bootstrap card border thickness

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add a thicker border around the whole card in my bootstrap 4 card. It was  supposed to be thicker, but nothing happened. I will give a snippet of my code here:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">
            <div class="card h-100">
                <img src="img/html.jpg" alt="HTML" class="card-img-top " style="display: block">
                <div class="card-block">
                    <h3 class="card-title"> Projects </h3>

                    <p class="font-weight-light"> hello world hello worldhello worldhello worldhello worldhello world</p>
                    <form action="https://www.w3schools.com/html/">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block">Learn More</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And my css:

```
 .card {
     border-style: 5px solid black;
     padding-bottom: 3%;
 }

 .row {
     padding-bottom: 15%;
 }
```

Is there anything I could do to get to the end result?

Thanks.

Comment: Take pride in your work and keep it well-formatted.  It'll save you much trouble. It also shows respect to those from whom you're asking help. Also, use an editor that shows mistakes like the extra quotation mark I removed.

Comment: Ok the way I cut it into here must have been bad

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`border-style` isn't valid when combining properties. Change it to `border` and it works.

```
 .card {
     border: 5px solid black;
 }
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/fbx1t2o9/)**

Comment: Works with bootstrap 4.4.x

Answer (score 3):

```
<div class="card" style="border: 2px solid #07bc4c"></div>
```

worked for me...

Answer (score 2):

**CSS WAY**

Rather than using `border-style` use `border:5px solid black;` your final output will look like this.

```
.card {
     border: 5px solid black;
     padding-bottom: 3%;
 }
```

**Bootstrap Way**

if you are using Bootstrap 5 you can also add bootstrap class `border border-5` on your card class.

Your final output will be look like this.

```
<div class="card h-100 border border-5">
</div>
```